# How to make combobox values searchable character by character (google like)?

Tags: vb.net

I am wondering how to make combobox values searchable character by character (google like). For example, if text box contains a list of employees (their names), if I type 'J' I will get an automatic generated list of names starting with J. If I type 'Ja' I will get an automatic list of names like, Jack, James, Jason...

Answer (score 2):

I think your looking for an autocomplete `function`.

Try: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1.

in the properties menu of the combobox goto the last expandable item;"*Misc*".
In the first item "*AutoCompleteCustomSource*" you can add the names you want.
In the second item "*AutoCompleteMode*" you should use the "Suggest" function.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the ComboBox to a bound column (1, 2, 3, etc.) and set the rowsource to a Table/Query.  Finally, set AutoExpand to Yes.

[image]

You can find some great samples that you can download, and play around with, from the two links below.

http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut19.htm

http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut17.htm